Ayrton Shunt/Universal Shunt

Is it correct that I calculated Rs for every range; 0-100mA, 0-150mA and 0-300mA?
Then, to find R2, I need to do Rs=R2+R3+R4? Like R2=Rs-(R3+R4)?
